# Good practice with conditional imports

Tags: python, import, maintainability

I have a module for configuration, `projectConfig`, to parse a sample sheet for a project:

```
class SampleSheetFields():
    FIELD_1 = "field1"
    FIELD_2 = "field2"


class SampleSheetFieldsOld():
    FIELD_1 = "field_1"
    FIELD_2 = "field_2"
```

I had been using the first class in other modules like this:

```
from projectConfig import SampleSheetFields as ssFields

class SomeClass

    def __init__(self):
        ...
        check(someContent, ssFields.FIELD_1)
```

The thing is I had developed my software using the reference to `ssFields` quite a lot. At some point new specifications said that the software should also use sample sheets with different field names. The quickest way I found to achieve that, without messing too much with the code, was to add the class `SampleSheetFieldsOld` in the `projectConfig` and to make a conditional import in my modules:

```
class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self, useOld):
        if useOld:
            from projectConfig import SampleSheetFieldsOld as ssFields
        else:
            from projectConfig import SampleSheetFields as ssFields

        ...
        check(someContent, ssFields.FIELD_1)
```

Note that the mandatory fields which are used have the same name so there is no  conflicting or missing field. The program works as expected.

My questions are:

1. How bad is this practice, if it is bad; and
2. How can I circumvent it to make a better and more sustainable code?

Comment: So you're just using the classes for their attributes? Or do they have actual functionality, too? Have you considered making them instances, or creating a class factory?

Comment: Their purpose is only to get the names, for matching purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably not the worst thing, but what I do find kind of problematic is the fact that you're now locked into two configuration options, old and new. What if you need to add a third or fourth etc. set someday? You won't be able to use a simple boolean test anymore.

Besides, it looks like your configuration options are all just simple string values, accessible via string keys. You don't need a class for that.

My suggestion is to forget about doing your configuration with the source code and use a configuration *file*. In your `projectConfig` you can have a `dict` which you initialize from a file, whose path/name can be provided on the command line or in whatever way is convenient. So `projectConfig.py` might go something like this:

```
config_options = {}

def load_configuration(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            # get key and value
            config_options[key] = value
```

Then everywhere you need to get a field name, just access `projectConfig.config_options['field_key']`, e.g.

```
from projectConfig import config_options

class SomeClass

    def __init__(self):
        ...
        check(someContent, config_options['FIELD_1'])
```

Or use `dict.get(key, default)` if there is a reasonable default value. This way, each time you need to switch to a different set of field names, you just create a new configuration file, and you don't have to touch the code.

Python's standard library includes a [`configparser` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) which can handle the loading for you.

Comment: In the likely event that the OP doesn't really need a class, this is even easier than creating them dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the class attributes, you could create a class factory, using [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) to create new classes, like:

```
FIELDS = dict(
    new=dict(FIELD_1="field1", FIELD_2="field2"),
    old=dict(FIELD_1="field_1", FIELD_2="field_2"),
}


def sample_sheet_field_factory(field_spec='new'):
    return type("SampleSheetFields", (object,), FIELDS[field_spec])
```

This can easily be extended to further sets of field specifications, and doesn't require a conditional import:

```
from wherever import sample_sheet_field_factory

class SomeClass(object):

    def __init__(self, use_old):
        ss_fields = sample_sheet_field_factory("old" if use_old else "new")
        check(some_content, ss_fields.FIELD_1)
```

You could also use a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), rather than a class, which would be a little more lightweight. Note edits for compliance with [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).